# Combinatorial norm alternative to $p$-norm

Tags: normed-spaces

We know $p$-norm as the formula $\left(\sum\limits_i\lvert x_i\rvert^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$, for some $p \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and vector $x \in X$. But have you ever seen this alternative below (?). I am asking for a friend:

$$\left(\sum\limits_i\lvert x_i\rvert^{p_i}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$$

In this case, set $\{p_i\}_{\#X}$ is such build that $p_i \in \mathbb{N}_{[1, \infty)}$ and variable $\rho$ is real and positive, but requires some further thoughts. My thoughts are that feasible sufficient conditions may be, e.g., on p-norm infimum and supremum for $p\to\infty$ and $p=1$ respectively. I would like to hear from you, guys. :-)

Comment: Hello :) No it's not possible, because it's not homogenous. But the sum of two norms is a norm like $\|x\|:=(\sum_i|x_i|^p)^{1/p}+(\sum_i|x_i|^q)^{1/q}$

Comment: Sad. At least I tried. Can I call it anything else except positive?